# CVS is owned by a user, but when files are imported into it, "root" is declared as the owner of those files

Tags: cvs, file-ownership

Hello I have just installed CVS server and have started importing files onto the server. How would I change the owner directly while file transfer or make the user the default owner of all the files being imported.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean the owner of the files once they are checked out, or the owner of the ,v files stored in the repository?

Comment: I meant the owner of v files, after the import is showing as root, though the owner has to be cvsd. This is giving me a problem during the initial checkout, since the client would not have permissions unless the owner owns the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book *Open Source Development with CVS* [(available online)](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/) describes how to set file permissions for a CVS repository.  See the section entitled ["Starting A Repository"](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#Starting%20A%20Repository).